# Running ansible insertLine command: Does the complete wrong thing, and i have no clue why

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrant-provision

so i have this line in my configuration.yml(ansible task)

```
- name: inserting password into database.php
  lineinfile: dest=/vagrant/htdocs/app/config/database.php insertbefore="^\s*'pgsql' => array" regexp="^\s*'password'" line="                     'password'  => '',"
```

And i am trying to replace this:

> ```
>    'sqlite' => array(
>         'driver'   => 'sqlite',
>         'database' => __DIR__.'/../database/production.sqlite',
>         'prefix'   => '',
>     ),
>     'mysql' => array(
>         'driver'    => 'mysql',
>         'host'      => 'localhost',
>         'database'  => 'echoit',
>         'username'  => 'root',
>         'password'  => 'vp45tudsdt',
>         'charset'   => 'utf8',
>         'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
>         'prefix'    => '',
>         'port'      => 8889
>     ),
> ```

```
    'pgsql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'forge',
        'username' => 'forge',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ),
```

When i try to grep the regex:

```
 grep "^\s*'pgsql' => array" ./htdocs/app/config/database.default.php


 'pgsql' => array(
```

And when i grep the other one:

```
 grep "^\s*'password'" ./htdocs/app/config/database.php


                'password'  => 'xxxxxxx',
                'password' => '',
             'password'  => '',
```

So my regular expressions match exactly the things i expect,
but then this  beforeline just doesn't work as i thouth it would, the ansible documentation on this functionality led me to believe that it would take the last match BEFORE  `'pgsql' => array`   but it just keeps replacing the very last path, in this case `'password' => '',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insertafter` and `insertbefore` are used to determine where to place new line **if `regexp` is not found**, it is not limiting the search area.
As per [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html):

> `regexp` – The regular expression to look for in every line of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice: use [template module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html):

Content of `dbconn.php.j2`:

```
<?php

// {{ ansible_managed }}

$DBHost = 'localhost';
$DBName = '{{ db.dbname }}';
$DBLogin = '{{ db_user.name }}';
$DBPassword = '{{ db_user.password }}';

?>
```

Params 'db', 'dbuser' are stored in `host_vars` and `group_vars`, password - in ansible `vault`.

Task in playbook:

```
- name: template config files
  template:
    src="sites_params/{{ sitename }}/templates/include/dbconn.php.j2"
    dest="/www/{{ sitename }}/www/include/dbconn.php"
    owner=apache
    group=apache
    mode=0644
    setype=httpd_sys_content_t
```

PS If you using git, exclude your config files such as dbconn from git, just put *sample* config (without passwords, salt etc) file into your project.

Comment: Okay, thanks, i will look into it :) the reason why i refrained from that was that i would have to litter my configuration files with ansible things, but maybe that is just the way to do it.